# linux, inotify - how to subscribe?

Tags: c++, linux, inotify

Can you please explain me the inotify mechanism? 
I’ve searched in the web about it, but what I understood is that if I want to see the changes in a file I have to do polling with the “read” function.
Is there any callback function which will notify me when the file has a change without polling?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I'm speculating that you are using some GUI library that handle events for you.

The better GUI libraries have a way to watch file descriptors. In GTK, it is [gtk_input_add_full](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-General.html#gtk-input-add-full); in Qt, [QSocketNotifier](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsocketnotifier.html) might work for you.

Comment: Fixed the links for you, with a bit more rep, you'll have no problem adding them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The inotify calls employ file descriptors.  Rather than polling you can use the returned FDs in the [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) family of calls.  It's not exactly a callback function but reduces the overhead you are concerned with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ev_io part of the libev library. This will allow you to set a callback for when the inotify fd is readable.

The documentation for libev can be found here: http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod

Answer (score 0):

No, inotify requires polling.

Registering a callback using signal (as suggested), is IMO worse then doing regular polling.

Comment: Duly noted, but can you elaborate *why* it would be worse? :)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi  One problem with signals is they do not mix very well with exceptions. The second problem is that signal handlers should do as minimal work as possible, and return.

Comment: Only if you through exceptions from the signal handler. And the fact that signal handlers should do as minimal work as possible does not mean that polling is preferred.
For example, your main code could create a pipe, setup the signal handler, then select on the pipe. The signal handler writes a single character to the pipe then exits. write is async-signal-safe. Control returns to your main code and select returns. You have a minimal signal handler and there is no need for polling.